# Error in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I am trying BargainFinderRQ.  I have given the access token in from the response it gave.I copied the code from the

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

I tried by changing the destination and arrival place.
I got this error.
May I know the elaboration of these errors.

My resulted errors are

***Error Type="WORKERTHREAD" Code="TRANSACTIONID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="691061236562728352"***

***Error Type="SERVER" Code="PIMHLP194" MessageClass="I" ShortText="27036"***

***Error Type="DEFAULT" Code="RULEID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="17500"***

***Error Type="SERVER" Code="MSG" MessageClass="I">No Availability<>***

***Error Type="ERR" Code="NAV" ShortText="No Availability"***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to contact the service provider for the same i.e., `sabre` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your service URL, I was using production endpoint url but after a while get same error s response and changed endpoint to test and now it responses correctly